# "merge" two tables in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables - tbl1 ,tbl2.

tbl1

```
(id int, name string):

(1, dan),
(2, shon),
(3, mimi),
(4, mali).
```

tbl2

```
(int id, second_name string):

(1, shiri),
(3, mili).
```

I want to do a "join" using the id but I don't want the ids that are in tbl1 and no in tbl 2 to disappear.

If I will do join the output will be:

```
(1, dan, shiri),
(3, mimi, mili).
```

but the output that I need is:

```
(1, dan, shiri),
(2, shon, *blank/null*),
(3, mimi, mili),
(4, mali, *blank/null*).
```

Please help me!

Comment: You are talking about an `[INNER] JOIN`, but you need another join (a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`) to keep rows with no matches. What DBMS are you using? You should always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Assuming you are using SQL Server, it would be like this:

```
SELECT tbl1.id, tbl1.name, tbl2.second_name 
    FROM tbl1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id
```

Comment: This doesn't have to be SQL Server. What you are showing is a standard SQL query that should run in about every RDBMS. The name is called `second_name` in `tbl2` by the way.